# looping multidimensional arrays with associative and index array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

$cars7=array(
     array(
     array('a1','b1','c1'),
     array('a2','b2','c2'),
     array('q'=>'a','b'=>'b','c'=>'c')
     )
    );

I tried the for loop with how we write the code for index array same i tried for mixed multidimensional array by showing error could not convert string to array.

----php multidimensional for loop.

```
$cars7=array(
          array(
          array('a1','b1','c1'),
          array('a2','b2','c2'),
          array('q'=>'a','b'=>'b','c'=>'c')
 )        
);



 for($i=0;$i<=count($cars7)-1;$i++) 
             {
             for($j=0;$j<=count($cars7[0])-1;$j++) 
            {
             echo $cars7[$i][$j].'<br><br>';

        }

    }
```

I don't know how to loop multidimensional array which contains index array and associative array.

I need help from expertise, Please correct the above code.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

**$cars[0]** is:

```
array(
      array('a1','b1','c1'),
      array('a2','b2','c2'),
      array('q'=>'a','b'=>'b','c'=>'c')
)
```

**$cars[0][0]** is:

```
array('a1','b1','c1')
```

**$cars[0][0][0]** is:

```
a1
```

You've got the right idea, you just need to start your loop a little "deeper".  And to loop through the arrays, use **foreach**:

```
foreach ( $cars[0] as $test )
{
   foreach ( $test as $entry )
   {
      echo $entry.'<br><br>';
   }
}
```

Comment: what if we need $cars[0][0] and $cars7[0][2]['q'] in loop any can we separate condition for index and associative two different.

Comment: I hope you got my point. like i need to access index array sometimes and associative sometime dynamically. if we put condition like if(something is associative array) possible.

Comment: There's no function to test if an array is associative or not, but you can use `key` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) with `if` statements to figure out whether you want to keep the key or not.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to get all the values is to use [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

```
$cars7 = array(
    array(
        array('a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
        array('a2', 'b2', 'c2'),
        array('q' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => 'c')
    )
);

array_walk_recursive ($cars7, function($value){
    echo $value . '<br>';
});
```

Result

```
a1
b1
c1
a2
b2
c2
a
b
c
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/a3WHb)